# clear file upload using jquery/javascript (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using jquery ajax to upload an excel file into the database. The problem is that after a successful file upload, I want to clear the file Upload so that if i press the button again it does not upload the same file (which it is currently)
I tried the below but no luck. I tried to put .value="" (no luck) .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnBankFileUpload').click(function () {
        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
        var fileUpload = $("#fileUploadMenu").get(0);
        var files = fileUpload.files;

        // Create FormData object  
        var fileData = new FormData();

        // Looping over all files and add it to FormData object  
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        }


        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Index',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
            processData: false, // Not to process data  
            data: fileData,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#uploadMessage').text(result);
                $('#lblFilePath').text(" ");
                var fileuploadmenu = $("#fileUploadMenu");
                fileuploadmenu.innerHTML = fileuploadmenu.innerHTML;
            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert(err.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
     });
    });
```

Comment: If `fileUploadMenu` is an input field, `$("#fileUploadMenu").val('');` should work.

Comment: Arggghh... i tried this before and it was not working :P Thanks for the answer. it worked, probably i tweaked something after i tried the last time.

Comment: I know it is not the same but should be, $("input[type=file]").val(''); does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#fileUploadMenu").val(null); //Clear Uploaded File
```